# Filtering rows which satisfy a condition per group in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have a big dataframe and I want to remove all rows if the number of rows for a given group based on a column in this datafram is less than a given number.
Here is an example:

```
x=1:6; y=c("A","B","B","B","C","C")
df<- data.frame(x,y)
```

If I group by variable y, I have three rows that belong to group "B". Here I want to remove all rows that don't satisfy this condition (<3 rows).
Expected output:

```
df
  x y
1 2 B
2 3 B
3 4 B
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

We can use `dplyr::filter()` and count the number of row in each group using `dplyr::n()`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  filter(n()>2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N >2], by  = y]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base R

```
t <- table(df$y)
df[df$y %in% names(t[t > 2]), ]

  x y
2 2 B
3 3 B
4 4 B
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R solution using the split, apply, combine approach:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$y), function(i) if(nrow(i) >= 3) { i }))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` solution which used `ave()`

```
res <-df[ave(seq(nrow(df)),df$y,FUN = length)>=3,]
```

and you will get

```
> res
  x y
2 2 B
3 3 B
4 4 B
```